# How to hide <li> within a certain <ol>? Jquery

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

I'm working on a project where I get names of clients:

```
<ol>J <li>John Doe</li> </ol>
```

and I want to show a list of ol's but with their list items hidden, so that when you click on a certain ol it will show the items within it.

Comment: You need to at least write some code. Hint .map()
Then we can help troubleshoot if you have trouble.

Comment: That's not valid html. Can't put text directly in an `<ol>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple select elements with jquery and `hide()` or `show()`

https://jsfiddle.net/29dnq7un/1/